# How to define variable inside of a text widget located in a separate dart file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `messages.dart` file that holds all the initial texts for different messages as Widgets.

```
Widget rest = Text('You should rest $restTime or $restTimeOr');
```

In the `main.dart` file, I'm defining the `$restTime` string value and in the column children, I want to call the `rest` widget from the `messages.dart` file.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String restTime = 'now';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          rest,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But it gives me the error in the `messages.dart` file that `restTime` is undefined. What am I missing here?
The complete `main.dart` file is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'example/messages.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String restTime = 'now';
  String restTimeOr = '2 hours later';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          rest,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the `messages.dart` file is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget rest = Text('You should rest $restTime or $restTimeOr');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `RestMessageWidget` in your `messages.dart` like this:

```
class RestMessageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? restTime;
  final String? restTimeOr;

  RestMessageWidget({@required this.restTime, @required this.restTimeOr});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('You should rest $restTime or $restTimeOr');
  }
}
```

You can then use the `RestMessageWidget` in `main.dart` like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String myRestTime = 'now';
  String myRestTimeOr = '2 hours later';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RestMessageWidget(restTime: myRestTime, restTimeOr: myRestTimeOr),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But it gives the error that the parameter `restTime` can't have a value of `null` in the `messages.dart` file.

Comment: You are getting the can't have a value null, becoz you have declared the value as Final
```final String restTime;
  final String restTimeOr;
```

Remove the final keyword, and you wont get the error..

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the answer to support null safety.

Comment: @sosualfred, the solution looks perfect now. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Define the rest message as a statelessWidget rather than a runtime instance. like this;

```
class RestMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  RestMessage(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text)
  }
}
```

and then use it in the main.dart like

```
Column...
children: [
          RestMessage(restMessageWithTime),
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please elaborate it a bit with the provided code in my question?

Comment: can you paste your messages.dart file

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question with the `messages.dart` file.

Comment: restTime is not visible in the messages.dart, please remove the messages.dart and just use the Text Widget in your main - this is 1st solution

2nd is the above where you define your "rest" widget in another file.